# return boolean value of an observable

Tags: angular

How do I make this function return a true or false value

```
  autenticacion(){
    let bool:boolean;
    this.auth.autenticacion(this.auth.getToken()).subscribe(data=>{
      if(data.data.token===this.auth.getToken()){
        bool=true;
      }else{
        bool=false;
      }
    });
    console.log(bool);
    return bool;
  }

this.autenticacion();
```

when I call the function I check that it returns me with the console log but it returns an undefined value someone knows how to make me return the false or the true

Comment: You are not returning anything in this function. `return` is missing

Comment: 1. Add `return bool;` after the `console.log(...)`. 2. Your if condition should be `data.data.token === this.auth.getToken()`. 3. Define bool as `bool: boolean;`

Comment: Just return `bool`

Comment: if I return the value still returns nothing

Comment: still showing undefined

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't subscribe to the observable if you want to return some value.
Try this instead:

```
autenticacion(){
  return this.auth.autenticacion(this.auth.getToken()).pipe(map(data=>{
    if(data.data.token==this.auth.getToken()){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }));
```

}

Then

```
this.autenticacion().subscribe(val => console.log(val)
```

Comment: Or just `return data.data.token === this.auth.getToken();`.

Comment: You are wrong. If you are using HttpClient, it returns an observable which is automatically unsubscribed upon receiving the API response. In that case you can definitely return a value.